# How can i get peers on my ethereum light node?

Tags: go-ethereum

I'm running a light node on a DigitalOcean VPS in order to use it to query data on the ethereum blockchain, but suddenly it stopped answering to any of my requests and i noticed that i always have 0 peers:

```
INFO [03-02|21:49:32.033] Looking for peers                        peercount=0 tried=16 static=0
INFO [03-02|21:49:42.036] Looking for peers                        peercount=0 tried=10 static=0
INFO [03-02|21:49:52.039] Looking for peers                        peercount=0 tried=5  static=0
INFO [03-02|21:50:02.043] Looking for peers                        peercount=0 tried=9  static=0
INFO [03-02|21:50:12.046] Looking for peers                        peercount=0 tried=8  static=0
INFO [03-02|21:50:22.050] Looking for peers                        peercount=0 tried=12 static=0
```

Here is how i'm running the node:

```
geth --syncmode "light" --http --http.port 8545 --http.addr 0.0.0.0 --http.corsdomain '*' --http.vhosts '*' --http.api 'eth,web3' --ws --wsaddr="0.0.0.0" --wsorigins="*"
```

Am i doing anything wrong here? Or is it a problem with the chain itself, since i read there aren't a lot of peers being served for light nodes?

Comment: Are you behind a firewall? Have you enabled p2p port (30303)? You can get some nodes from ethernodes.org/nodes.

Comment: I did sudo ufw allow 30303; sometimes i get one peer but other times it drops to zero. How can i add those nodes?

Comment: From the geth console use [`admin.addPeer(<enode>)`](https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/rpc/ns-admin#admin_addpeer) with the '<enode>' from the link. Just be aware not every node supports the light protocol.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The only problem is that i'm running geth in the background, so it won't allow me to open the console. Is there another way to do that?

Comment: Use the command `geth attach` to connect to a running instance. You can specify the IPC file `geth attach ~/.ethereum/geth.ipc` (on linux). If the `admin` api is enabled you can use JSON RPC commands (read documentation in the link).

Comment: Awesome, thank you a lot @Ismael!